# Ratio of two binomial distributions

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, ratio

How to estimate
$$
E\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right]
$$
for two independent random variables $X\sim Bin(n,p)$ and $Y\sim Bin(m,p)$ ?
Are there any connection with $\frac{n}{n+m}$ e.g., $1-\varepsilon\leq E\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right]/\frac{n}{n+m}\leq 1+\varepsilon$?

Comment: How do you define $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ on the event $\{X=Y=0\}$?

Comment: Oops. Then, let I assume $0$. i.e, I want to estimate $E[f(X,Y)]$, where $f(X,Y)=0$ if $X=Y=0$ and  $f(X,Y)=\frac{X}{X+Y}$ otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

Note that, for every nonnegative integers $(x,y)$, $$\frac{x}{x+y}\mathbf 1_{x\ne0}=\int_0^1xs^{x+y-1}\mathbf 1_{x\ne0}ds$$
Integrating this, one gets $$E\left(\frac X{X+Y}\mathbf 1_{x\ne0}\right)=\int_0^1E(Xs^{X-1}\mathbf 1_{X\ne0})E(s^Y)ds$$
Now, $Y$ is a Binomial and $X\mathbf 1_{X\ne0}$ a positive-Binomial random variables, hence
$$E(s^X\mathbf 1_{X\ne0})=\left[(ps+q)^n-q^n\right]\qquad E(s^Y)=(ps+q)^m$$
here $q = 1-p$.
By differentiation, $$E(Xs^{X-1}\mathbf 1_{X\ne0})=\frac d{ds}E(s^X\mathbf 1_{X\ne0})=np(ps+q)^{n-1}$$
Thus,
$$E\left(\frac X{X+Y}\mathbf 1_{X\ne0}\right)=\int_0^1 np\cdot (ps+q)^{n+m-1}ds=\frac n{n+m} \cdot (1-q^{n+m})$$ from which the desired estimates follow.