# Variance of a ratio of two Poissons

Tags: self-learning, variance, ratio

My question is related to [Ratio of two binomial distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2863271/ratio-of-two-binomial-distributions). Assume $X\sim \text{Poisson}(p\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\text{Poisson}(q\lambda)$ where $p,q>0$ are constants. I have interest in the distribution of $$ W=\dfrac{X}{X+Y},$$ specifically, the variance of such a ratio. From the explanation in the answer in the related question I managed to calculate $E[W]$, using (EDIT:)

$$
E\left[\dfrac{X}{X+Y}\right]\mathbb{I}_{x,y\neq(0,0)} = \int_0^1 xs^{x+y-1}ds\\
=\int_0^1E\left[Xs^{X-1}\right]E\left[s^Y\right]ds
$$
from the description of the variables
$$
E\left[s^X\right] = \exp\left[p\lambda\left(s^t-1\right)\right],\;
E\left[s^Y\right] = \exp\left[q\lambda\left(s^t-1\right)\right],$$
and $$
E\left[Xs^{X-1}\right] = \dfrac{d}{ds}E\left[s^X\right] = p\lambda\exp[p\lambda(s-1)]
$$
then,
$$
\int_0^1 p\lambda e^{p\lambda(s-1)}e^{q\lambda(s-1)}ds =
\int_0^1 p\lambda e^{p\lambda(s-1) + q\lambda(s-1)} ds\\
= p\lambda\int_0^1 e^{(p\lambda + q\lambda)(s-1)}ds\\
= \dfrac{p}{p+q}e^{-\lambda(p+q)}\left[e^{\lambda(p+q)}-1\right]\\
= \dfrac{p}{p+q}\left[1-e^{-\lambda(p+q)}\right]
$$
Which essentially is the ratio of $p/(p+q)$ since the exponential term vanishes with moderate values of $\lambda$.  I am having trouble using the same approach to find $E[W^2]$ so that I can get the variance. I'd appreciate any help. Also, for practical purposes I am assuming that the case $X=0$ and $Y=0$ is not likely to happen since $\lambda$ is relatively large (typically > 50). I understand that in theory, there is a positive probability that both $X$ and $Y$ can be zero. I am also aware of approximations to that variance, but I wanted a distinct approach.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I think you need to consider the conditional distribution given that $X+Y\ne0$, I don't think you can just say "well we only divide by 0 with a small probability so we don't need to worry about it". 
How did you calculate the mean? Did you condition on the denominator not being $0$?

Comment: I have edited my question to show how I calculated the mean. Again, is based on the comment in the related question. Thanks.